# How do I redirect ONE url to write around a typo in a link "index.ph"?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

A coworker of mine send out some materials that have a link to a URL like: www.oursite.com/important/index.ph

I want to redirect only that exact URL to the correct URL:

www.oursite.com/important/index.php

Without messing with the original URL. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(important/index\.ph)$ /$1p [L,NC,R=302]
```